# Trouble "removing" a shadow-root from a code

Tags: css, themes

sorry if this sounds really dumb, but i'm not sure how to get rid of something.
there's this button at the bottom right of my blog at http://bigams.tumblr.com/ , supposedly a "credit", but the person actually plagiarised the whole theme, so i'm looking to remove the credit.

i can remove the bit that changes what the button looks like, as there's this bit:

```
.cred { background: {color:post};outline: 1px solid {color:border}; border: 1px outset {color:post};  bottom: 10px; left: 10px; position: fixed; padding: 2px 5px; text-transform: lowercase; font-family: bitxmap; font-size: 10px; } .cred a { text-decoration: none; } .cred:active { border: 1px inset {color:post}; }
```

but i can't find the LITERAL part that says

```
<a href="http://jubileethemes.tumblr.com">theme</a>
```

and it's really annoying. how am i supposed to get rid of it?

also, if you need the full code (i messed with it a little but this is the default), here's the link: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NJtAbtqF

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about it, your blogs bottom right is unreachable.

look at the scroll bar, and what happens after like 5 minutes of trying to make it to the bottom(it practically disappears)

[image]

[image]

**If you really, really want to get rid of it:**

i found this in your code:

[image]

Just **CTR+F** and look for

> http://jubileethemes.tumblr.com

*here it is after removal:*

http://pastebin.com/KR1p905x

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Line 202.

Try this: View Source in your browser, click CTRL+F to find, type in "jubileethemes" and it will show you where it is.

Open the page in your text editor, and you can delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
.cred { 
    background: {color:post};
    outline: 1px solid {color:border};
    border: 1px outset {color:post};
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-family: bitxmap;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: none;
}



  .cred a {
      text-decoration: none;
}





 .cred:active {
           border: 1px inset {color:post};
}
```

Add display:none; to .cred